# How to set a default value as Range<Int> when I use a ForEach method?

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I want to know how to set a default value of `count` as `Range<Int>` when I use a `ForEach` method.

because of using an array object created by an async method, when I use `ForEach` method I have to set a default value.

If I set the default value just `0`, I get an error below:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'
```

How could I set a value as `Range<Int>` then?

---

Here are the codes:

*I want to set `0` as the default value

ContentView.swift

```
...
@EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

ForEach(0..<appState.arrayInfos?.count ?? 0 ,id: \.self){ index in
     VStack{
         InfoRow(no: index,info:appState.arrayInfos![index] )
     }
}
...
```

AppState.swift

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {

    @Published var arrayInfos:[ArrayInfos]?

}

...
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            do{ self.arrayInfos = try JSONDecoder().decode([ArrayInfos].self, from: responseData)
            }catch{
                print("Error: did not decode")
                return
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
...
```

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use dynamic variant of `ForEach`, otherwise it will not be updated when data appeared

```
ForEach(appState.arrayInfos?.indices ?? 0..<0, id: \.self) { index in
     VStack {
         InfoRow(no: index, info: appState.arrayInfos![index])
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to do it following your code. But then I get this error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` in here `appState.arrayInfos![index]`.

Comment: Closed range includes 0 index, my fault - see updated with empty range as fix (now tested with Xcode 12.1)